# Limitations of Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic

I am researching logistic regression limitations, I am new on this subject, I could not find very clear information about logistic regression limitations in the literature. I would be very grateful if you could share your information and guide me about what the logistic regression limitations are.

Thank you very much

Comment: This needs more focus. What would count as a limitation to you? There could be any number of comments along the lines of "the problem with this cat is that it is not a dog". Or, the problem with logistic regression is that it is not familiar to my target readership, or not feasible in MS Excel (if that's true), and so on.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of potential limitations, but for most of these there also extensions/versions/approaches that address these:

- It's only for binary/binomial outcomes: there's extensions to ordered and unordered categories.
- Partial or perfect separation can happen (e.g. one predictor - or a combination of multiple ones - can split results perfectly in all 1s or 0s): potential solutions incl. Firth penalized likelihood, exact or Bayesian logistic regression
- There's issues with inference for sparse data (low or very high number of cases) in terms of e.g. estimation, confidence interval coverage, type I error etc.: similar solutions to the previous bullet help.
- People mostly thing of the version of LR, where you assume predictors have a linear effect ("cannot model non-linear effects"): Splines or other non-linear terms are the obvious solution, although to some extent you still have to specify them (rather than things like XGBoost or neural networks "automatically creating their own non-linear functions").
- You need to create your own features (often stated in contrast to, say, neural networks, although to be fair these also benefit from being given strong features): to a considerable extent true. Although you could regard a neural network as a particular form of LR (i.e. trained using gradient descent, with, if there's multiple layers, a particularly weird spline across many features...).
- Logistic regression does not work all that well with certain types of input such as images or text. There are of course techniques that can be used: e.g. TF-IDF features for text help, and using embeddings from (pre-trained) neural networks (e.g. word2vec embeddings, or pooling layer outputs from some convolutional neural network) as inputs can be useful.
- Hyperparameter tuning: per default there are no hyperparameters for logistic regression that one can tune. Even with elastic net logistic regression just has 2 penalty parameters (and perhaps one more if we considered the relaxed elastic net), while other models like XGBoost, LightGBM, tabular neural networks etc. have a lot more hyperparameters that one can tune to potentially get more effective regularization. However, note that [in some settings, it can be very hard to find something better than a well-constructed logistic regression](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jclinepi.2019.02.004). For what it's worth, there's all the cautionary advice about "you better use the 1-SE-rule instead of picking the seemingly best parameters from cross-validation, or else you may have overfit" about LASSO/ridge/elastic-net LR, which appears to have a lot of merit.
- LR does not deal well with high dimensional categorical variables by dummy coding them/does not account for them being a-priori similar/ignores that observations from related subjects are correlated: random effects/hierarchical logistic regression and various other version for particular applications (e.g. spatial data) can do this (as well as a bunch of other useful things).
- Non-linear interactions are rarely modelled in practice, and it gets increasingly difficult to specify these. However, if you suspect them for some combination of predictors, it can be done.
- LR cannot reflect what I already know about the problem: Bayesian logistic regression let's you specify prior distributions to reflect your prior knowledge.
- The linear model vs. logistic regression (some people like to model event occurrence 1/0 using linear regression) discussion.
- The interpretability of odds ratios debate, where some people argue that risk differences are preferable, some people prefer the number needed to treat and some rate ratios (all 4 options have some merit in some circumstances, of course). Plus, you can fit a logistic regression using the logit link and get different effect measures from the model fit under certain assumptions.
- The collapsability of the odds ratio debate: i.e. odds ratio is non-collapsible, while a rate ratio is, which has some implications on covariate adjustment (and what happens when it's mis-specified).
- Logistic regression does not sound cool enough when making research proposals and people are looking for buzzwords like machine learning or neural networks. However, the solution is easy: logistic regression also meets the typical definitions of machine learning and/or artificial intelligence, so just describe it as such (I cannot remember the origin, but there's a joke on this that goes:"It's artificial intelligence when you talk to the investors, machine learning in the job advert and logistic regression when you do it).